# Row Compare in PCollections Apache Beam

Tags: apache-beam

I have to parse a large CSV file, row wise and each element of the row needs to be compared against the respective element from the previous row. What is the best way of doing this with Beam? I would prefer to use Java code

Comment: Beam doesn't guarantee the elements ordering since two corresponding lines can be processed on different workers because of split/shuffle/etc. Do you have another relation between two rows, that should be compared, other than just initial order in the input file?

Comment: I could introduce to an ID column to ensure sequence for these rows. But does Beam support row wise element comparison? If so, is there Java implementation that I can follow

Comment: I am basically trying to create an Custom Object from each row of the CSV and then compare their respective attribute values

Comment: It's up to user to compare the rows, though it should not be an issue in most cases. The main difficulty is to have two comparing rows together. One of the option could be to group these records by some key and then have them grouped. Maybe, it would be easier to find a solution if you could give more details about your problem and expected results.

Comment: I am looking to ingest a CSV file which has details about travel times each cab would take from same source to same destination, ex: if a 2 cabs travel from a city center - to an airport, what is the travel time each cab takes, assuming commonality in their cab make and build. In this case I would like to create a "Trip" object from the details available in the CSV and compare their travel times and assign a rating to the cab taking the least time

Comment: https://github.com/aromanenko-dev/beam-tutorial/blob/master/analytic/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/tutorial/analytic/SalesPerCarsBrand.java is the example I am trying to work with, except that I am trying to create my "Trip" object and use it in "ParseAndConvertToKV" step and do the comparison between "Trip1" and "Trip2" - Thanks BTW for your responses, noob trial! @AlexeyRomanenko

Comment: Thanks for details. If you have an information what are the source and destination in every row in your input CVS, then I would suggest to create a KV after, where a key is hash([source,destination]) and a value is other row information. So, you will have a PCollection<KV<K, V>> and you can do GroupByKey and after you will have all cab times for the same source/destination in one place where you can compare them.

Comment: Could you possibly give me a git GIST of your suggestion?

Comment: I don't have a gist for now but you can easily adapt my example of "SalesPerCarsBrand.java", that you mentioned above, to your needs - just create a proper key (I guess it will be a composite key of [source,destination])), then do GroupByKey and sort your values (cab times) inside you GBK results (since they will be associated to the same key).